# When you run `update-rc.d myscript default` - what is called on startup/shutdown?

Tags: bash, startup, reboot, init, init.d

What gets called on startup/shutdown when you run `update-rc.d myscript default`?

Docs seem fuzzy, I want concrete. I am guessing that this happens:

At startup (specifically at entry to runlevel 2, multiuser), this command is executed:

```
/etc/init.d/myscript start
```

And at shutdown/reboot the same script is called as:

```
/etc/init.d/myscript stop
```

Is that all that is really happening here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is correct.

Taken from `man update-rc.d`:

> If  defaults is used then update-rc.d will make links to start the ser‐
>          vice in runlevels 2345 and to stop the service in  runlevels  016.   By
>          default  all the links will have sequence number 20, but this should be
>          overridden if there are dependencies. For example if daemon  B  depends
>          on  A,  then  A must be started before B and B must be killed before A.
>          You accomplish this by supplying two NN  arguments.  In  general,  core
>          daemons  should start early and be killed late, whilst applications can
>          start late and be killed early.

More information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto), look for the "Installing custom init-scripts" section.